# PHP merging every other array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-merge

just curious if someone knows how to merge every other sub array,

aka

```
$tmp = array();

$tmp[0] = array(false);
$tmp[1] = array(false);

$tmp[2] = array(false);
$tmp[3] = array(false);

$tmp[4] = array(false);
$tmp[5] = array(false);
```

or ....
0+1
2+3
4+5

something like this i think?

```
$i=0; $new=array();
foreach($tmp as $k=>$v) {
  $tmp[$k] = $v;
  if($i=$k-1) { 
    $new[] = $tmp[$i] + $tmp[$i-1]; /* or something ridiculous like that */
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: What exactly was the point of editing this AND downvoting it, especially after it's been solved and accepted. Ridiculous....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) and [`array_merge`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) you can come up with a fairly simple solution

```
<?php

$result = array_chunk($tmp, 2);

foreach ($result as &$chunk)
{
    $chunk = array_merge($chunk[0], $chunk[1]);
}
```

Comment: In case a chunk has more than two elements,  `call_user_func_array('array_merge', $chunk)` works as well.

Comment: Ooh! Even better. Thanks for the input.

Comment: even though this looks tricky and "nice" - I would never write such not obvious code in production (yes, for me it looks a little difficult to read and understand)

Answer (score 2):

```
$new = array();
for ($i = 0, $cnt = count($tmp); $i < $cnt; $i += 2) {
    $new[] = $tmp[$i] + $tmp[$i + 1];
}
```

Comment: An array with an odd number of entries causes this to fail with "Notice: Undefined offset:" and "Fatal error: Unsupported operand types", as I noted below.

Comment: @nickb: indeed, but I didn't have a goal to do the all @ehime's work, but gave him an idea of how to write the base. Btw, it will fail in the case when `$tmp[$i]` is not an array, but an object, and I don't handle that, because it's out of the question scope.

Comment: there's always an even number and in the case its an object you can always use string casting $mp = (array)$tmp; so its a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the array contains an even number of entries. If this is not the case, or if you're looking to merge 0 + 1, 1 + 2, 2 + 3, change the increment on `$i` to 1, and change the assignment of `$j` to `$j = count( $tmp) - 1`

```
$tmp = array();

$tmp[0] = array(false);
$tmp[1] = array(false);

$tmp[2] = array(true);
$tmp[3] = array(true);

$new = array();
for( $i = 0, $j = count( $tmp); $i < $j; $i += 2)
{
    $new[] = array_merge( $tmp[$i], $tmp[$i+1]);
}
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    bool(false)
    [1]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    bool(true)
    [1]=>
    bool(true)
  }
}
```

Comment: You could write this with [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) too.